# Harry potter fanfic where Harry has to look after a fake magical baby for class

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Looking for a Harry potter fan fiction story with a Harry/Snape pairing, where it's a sex education class at Hogwarts where Harry have to look after a fake baby, but the baby being magical is very real, also has a fake pregnancy in it as well.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please take the [tour], look at [help], [ask] and [answer] to get a feel for how the site works.

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fan-fiction-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1 after also particularly good for prompts to solicit further details to [edit] in.

Comment: Do you have any idea where you might have read it?

Comment: I think originally read it on fanfiction.net or adultfanfiction

Comment: @Annaw you can [edit] that in

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it is ["A Marriage of Convenience" Chapter 18](http://hp.adult-fanfiction.org/story.php?no=600097277&chapter=18), by Nina Sweets?

This is only one chapter of a long work, but it does feature Harry/Snape, a fake baby for class which is at least appearing to be alive, and a fake pregnancy potion.

Comment: Good find! Will be interesting to see if this is the one

Comment: No it's not that one the while story was about the fake baby and Harry taking care of it for a class project.